# c++ strict-aliasing rules compile error with Qt and QLinkedList

Tags: c++, qt, templates, compiler-errors, g++

```
In file included from /usr/local/Qt/linux-g++/include/QtCore/QLinkedList:2,
  from /home/bamboo/Packages/Parser.h:17,
  from /home/bamboo/Packages/Module.cpp:6:
/usr/local/Qt/linux-g++/include/QtCore/qlinkedlist.h: In member function 'void QLinkedList<T>::clear() [with T = int]':
/usr/local/Qt/linux-g++/include/QtCore/qlinkedlist.h:294: error: dereferencing pointer 'y' does break strict-aliasing rules
/usr/local/Qt/linux-g++/include/QtCore/qlinkedlist.h:293: note: initialized from here
/usr/local/Qt/linux-g++/include/QtCore/qlinkedlist.h:294: error: dereferencing pointer 'y' does break strict-aliasing rules
/usr/local/Qt/linux-g++/include/QtCore/qlinkedlist.h:293: note: initialized from here
```

where in big lines class `Module` contains a member template like: `Parser<int>` and the class parser is defined:

```
template <typename T> class Parser
{
   // some stuff
   QLinkedList<T> stuff;
};
```

and this piece of code compiles nicely with `gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3` and nicely with `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2` and fails with `g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5` ... and I have no idea why? Anyone has seen this error message and anyone know what this might mean?... and more importantly how to solve it?

Comment: additonally this article does pretty good describe it: http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Comment: Yup,  I saw that post before posting this question, and the Qt header is actually using that technique ... So this must be something different.

Comment: You may get better help if you make a http://sscce.org so others can compile it and poke at it.  What Qt version btw?

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing means that a pointer `int *i` points to the same address as `double *d`.
So if

```
int i = 5;
int *pi = &i:
double *d = pi;
```

here `d` is aliasing `pi`.

this is in c99 >illegal<

I don't know how exactly c++ treats it, but I can't imagine it is welcome.

If you want to test a code where it will be getting funny, try this code in different optimisation levels.

You will get differen results with gcc 4.2

```
uint32_t anint;

int main(int arg, char** argv)
{
    foo ((uint64_t *)&anint);
    return 0;
}

void foo (uint64_t *dblptr)
{
    anint = 88;
    *dblptr = 86;
    dosmthng (anint);
}

void dosmthng (uint32_t val)
{
    printf ("%d\r\n", val);
}
```

if you do -O2 or higher the output will be 88. because the compiler expects you to respect the strict-aliasing rule and expects `*dblptr` as never been used in this code, and jsut takes the line out.

If you any way see no way of working wihtout aliasing, you can give the compiler the param `-fno-strict-aliasing`. This forces GCC to do not any optimisation based on this expection.

But anyway in C it is not strict ISO C code if you do wrong type punning.

(So if it may ease you, a lot of C code on famous programms gets compiled with `-fno-strict-aliasing`)